# Associative array value += in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, associative-array

I have an Invoice items list. I create a tax breakup array (associative array) to store unique tax percentages and their tax amount.

[image]

```
$taxbreakup=array(); 
@foreach($invoiceinfo->invoiceitems as $invoice_items)
    $taxbreakup[$invoice_items->tax_percentage]+=$invoice_items->tax_amount;
@endforeach
```

Group Tax percentage and display total tax amount for particular tax percentage

[image]

```
@foreach($taxbreakup as $key => $value)
 
 <tr>

  <td colspan="12"></td>
  <td class="btmlft" colspan="2">GST ({{number_format($key,2)}})%</td>
  <td class="btmlft rghtbrd alignright">{{number_format(($value),2) }}</td>
  </tr>
 
 @endforeach
```

I got an undefined index error.

Comment: _I got an undefined index error._ The please show us the complete error message and indicate in your code snippets which line it is relating to

Comment: It is not a `+=` issue if you have an undefined index. `$taxbreakup[$invoice_items->tax_percentage]` => The index represented by `$invoice_items->tax_percentage` does not exist in `$taxbreakup`.

Comment: dd `$taxbreakup` before the foreach loop you will find the cause of this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `+=` the variable you are accumulating the result into must be initialized, in your case it does not yet exist and is not initialized.

Even if you wanted to do

```
$arr['val'] = $arr['val'] + 1;
```

the receiving variable need to have been created.

So I would use

```
$taxbreakup=array(); 
@foreach($invoiceinfo->invoiceitems as $invoice_items)
    // check accumulator exists before using it
    if ( ! isset($taxbreakup[$invoice_items->tax_percentage]) ) {
        $taxbreakup[$invoice_items->tax_percentage] = 0; 
    }
    $taxbreakup[$invoice_items->tax_percentage] += $invoice_items->tax_amount;
@endforeach
if ( ! isset($arr['hello']) ) { $arr['hello'] = 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this variable $taxbreakup is empty, check $taxbreakup empty and then do the foreach